# Difference between HttpApplication.User (in Global.asax) and Controller.User (in an MVC Controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cas

We're using a third-party authentication mechanism ([CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), via the [.NET CAS Client](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/.Net+Cas+Client)). As part of this, we need to extract some data about the logged in user.

We have achieved this by accessing the `HttpApplication.User` instance from Global.asax (a `DotNetCasClient.Security.CasPrincipal` in our scenario). However, we need it to work from a controller.

The problem is that from a controller we have access to `Controller.User`, the instance of which is a plain old `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal`, which is not what we need.

So:

- Why are these instances not the same?
- Is it possible to get the `HttpApplication.User` from within a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there has got to be a better way to do this -- but in the meantime, I would suggest using `HttpContext.Current.Items["YourKey"]` and then accessing the `Context.Item` in your controller.

See [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inherit from Controller and override `OnAuthorization`?

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.User   // CasPrincipal ???
......
```

Comment: Sadly not; that user is also a `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal`.